# Is there a good reason not to name most digital signals in the flavor of COPI/CIPO (MOSI/MISO)

Tags: digital-communications

I have always been irritated from the fact that one of the biggest stumbling blocks that I encounter is determining a reference in digital IOs.

I mean my issue is that RX and TX is reference dependent. COPI/CIPO removes that uncertainty in cases where a controller is well defined. (PCIe, for instance)

Is there a good reason not to implement this scheme in other peripherals?

Comment: I'm afraid you've put a discussion forum question on a Q&A site. Any answers will have to be opinions. VTC for that reason.  (You'll get a few "Don't ask opinion questions, tch! Except my opinion here, that's alright obviously. So here's what I think..." comments, there always are :-) )

Comment: Argh, I knew that it was a bit off, took the shot anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky. It’s reminiscent of the RS-232 headaches of DTE vs. DCE and crossover vs. non-crossover cables.

Basically you have to check. Read the specifications carefully. Draw a diagram if you have to.

For example, TX and RX for the PCIe slot are from the host point of view. The M.2 NVMe spec on the other hand, they’re from the card’s point of view.

SATA is even worse. The pairs are labeled ‘A’ and B’. And SATA often coexists with NVMe on cabling and drive connectors.